# Android project cannot run why

Tags: android

[image]

I download the project from https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/nav-drawer.html Its name is NavigationDrawer.zip

Comment: it is a very simple question，someone can give a answer?

Comment: configure your framework

Answer (score 0):

Right click **src** directory and choose **Mark Directory As** -> Resources Root.

Answer (score 0):

You can follow this step

```
1) press CTRL+ALT+SHIFT+S.
2) Under Project Setting go to Facets.
3) click + button and add Android-gradle.
4) select your project name.
5) Apply and ok.
6) Goto File and Invalidate cache / restart
```

or you can check first either sdk-path is correct.

```
Open local.properties file and make sure it same with your path sdk.
```

Example:

```
# change the SDK path below to match the folder on your system
sdk.dir=D\:\\Android\\android-sdk
```

Comment: Project Sync
         The project 'NavigationDrawer' is not a Gradle-based project

Comment: i do as you say,but i find it is not bulit by Gradle

Answer (score 0):

Project Sync
         The project 'NavigationDrawer' is not a Gradle-based project

I think this the answer,the project is not built by Gradle